# Was a 5000 year old flying machine discovered in Afghanistan?

Tags: history, machines

If you search on Google "5000 year old flying machine discovery", there are lot of article and YouTube videos available claiming 5000 year old flying machine called "Vimana" discovered in Afghanistan. When US soldiers try to remove the flying machine they just vanish.

**Does the flying machine really exist? Did soldiers really disappear when trying to remove the flying machine?**

Youtube [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBlwhVyZxmQ) conversation about this flying machine discovery in Afghanistan

Article [link](http://beforeitsnews.com/unexplained-phenomena/2012/10/secret-5000-year-old-flying-machine-discovered-2430726.html) about this flying machine discovery

Quotes:

> What caused the sudden rush of these most powerful leaders of the
>   Western World to go to Afghanistan, this report continues, was to
>   directly view the discovery by US Military scientists of what is
>   described as a "Vimana" entrapped in a "Time Well"  that has already
>   caused the "disappearance" of at least 8 American Soldiers trying to
>   remove it from the cave it has been hidden in for the past estimated
>   5,000 years.

Comment: Can you please include a link to one of the articles and preferably quote some part that shows exactly what those articles are claiming?

Comment: There are lot of articles available in Google. But i have posted the links i read. Thanks

Comment: more "ancient aliens". Erich von Daenicken would be proud.

Comment: http://johnkettler.com/worldwide-exclusive-vimana-gods-stolen-laughs-thieves/  ;-)

Comment: Madhu can you copy/paste the most relevant part of the links, and quote it in your question? It's fairly important or people will have problem taking your question seriously. I can help you out with formatting, and formulating the question, but you need to put in the quote yourself.

Comment: Especially because links are always subject to [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) which renders the question useless without qoutes.

Comment: Curiously, the topic of this question is almost an exact synopsis for the 2008 movie ['The Objective'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Objective) (US soldiers vanish investigating 'Vimana' in Afghanistan).

Comment: @Richard: that comment would form the basis of a good answer. See also http://wayback.archive.org/web/20120331170834/http://www.hvk.org/articles/0601/100.html

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Well, I don't know if the movie was inspired by specific extant claims relating to vimana or vice versa (it wouldn't be the first time esoteric discourse was directly inspired by a work of fiction, cf. [Vril](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vril)). Alternatively, it may be completely coincidental.

Comment: I tried to listen to the youtube link but baled at the point where the expert declared CERN is a "stargate". Just after he declared that we are seeing the solar system fill up with alien flying ships which are having visible effects on saturn a jupiter. He didn't seem to think any of this needed to have *evidence* it was so obvious. Do we really have to take these ramblings seriously?

Comment: @RichardTerrett - or, even simpler, all of the info on the internet is a viral marketing campaign for the movie.

Answer (score 14):

"Vimanas" are a recurring myth based on a mixture of total lies and modern ignorance. This video does a good job explaining why:

[Ancient Aliens Debunked](http://ancientaliensdebunked.com/references-and-transcripts/vimanas/)

Quote from the video:

> The Vimanika Shastra is not an actual ancient text. It was channeled, or dictated, to the author from the spirit world in 1918.
>   The spirit who supposedly dictated the text claimed to be and ancient seer named Bharadvada, who is prominent in some ancient writings, so I guess that is what is supposed to give this text credibility – that is, the idea that the ghost of someone ancient supposedly dictated it.
>   But they’re not even sure if that version of the story is true, because the first mention of any of this is in 1952 by the guy who supposedly found and translated this text from 1918, so as far as anyone knows he could have made the whole channelled by a famous ghost story up in 1952.

If that doesn't float your boat, there's [a whole Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaim%C4%81nika_Sh%C4%81stra) about them.

As for Merkel, Obama and Cameron making visits to Afghanistan, that's hardly surprising or rare. There is a war going on there, after all, and leaders have made [diplomatic visits, while also visiting their troops](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/05/01/barack-obama-afghanistan_n_1468525.html). (Merkel did the same again [just yesterday](http://www.thehindu.com/news/international/world/angela-merkel-makes-surprise-visit-to-afghanistan/article4702237.ece).)

These visits are always kept under wraps until the last minute for reasons of safety. Again, nothing unusual about that.

I don't believe there's any other claim in the video based on any evidence. The rest is just rumours.

Comment: Linked site is infected with malware: "Google Chrome has blocked access to ancientaliensdebunked.com for now."
Can anybody approve this? Is there an alternative source for the video?

Comment: @StephanSchielke I'm sure it's a temporary issue. They probably got hacked. Undoubtedly they'll be back up again.